# Cannot sendKeys in a dropdown search bar Java Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to enter London into the following dropdown search bar but it does not sendKeys. Struggling to understand how to grab the element correctly? I can get the search to load at least..

[Search Bar picture (when clicking People)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE6j9.png)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/Desktop/chromedriver" );

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.dlapiper.com/en/uk/");

    WebElement peopleButton = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-1"));
    peopleButton.click();

    WebElement peopleAutoComplete = driver.findElement(By.id("peopleglobalsearchbox"));

    peopleAutoComplete.sendKeys("London");
```

Comment: post the markup (html).  You want to send keys to the <input = "text"> tag.

Comment: thanks for replying - https://pastebin.com/ENnbvXVX here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fail for two reasons. First, you are finding the wrong element. Second, you will identify it before it is visible on the page.

When using Selenium sendKeys, you should be referencing an input field, not the div. In this case:

```
By.xpath("//div[@id='peopleglobalsearchbox']//input");
```

Visibility of the element is more intricate, but Selenium has done well to support these challenges.

```
    public WebElement waitUntilElementIsVisible(By by) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
        return driver.findElement(by);
    }
```

The above method will wait until the locator is visible, then it will send keys.

Comment: Wow swift response, I am quite new to this so a couple of questions.
1) When you use the X Path, you're still finding the ID of peopleglobalsearchbox, so what is wrong with using what I did and why do you need the other items around it like //div//input etc..

2) When I copy and paste this into IntelliJ i have errors as its not complete - how do i get send keys to work with this?

view-source:https://www.dlapiper.com/en/uk/